# laravel eloquent like does not work

Tags: php, arrays, database, laravel, eloquent

I have a very simple database structure and query.
What I want is getting some rows with %like%, but it gets nothing.
Here is my query:

```
$kslr=DB::table('kisiler')->select('*')->where('dogumgunu','%LIKE%',"29-12")->get();
```

When I write var_dump($kslr) it gives me an empty array.

I have three persons in kisiler table whose "dogumgunu" columns are: "29-12-1987", "29-12-1986" 
and "24-12-1991.

So the the query should return me 2 of these but it gets nothing,
By the way the "dogumgunu" column in my table is a "text" structure whichh is set utf-8.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not put wildcards in the operator, put them in the searched term!

```
$kslr = DB::table('kisiler')
       ->select('*')
       ->where('dogumgunu','LIKE',"%29-12%")
       ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
where('dogumgunu','%LIKE%',"29-12")
```

should be

```
where('dogumgunu','LIKE',"%29-12%")
```

LIKE is an operator

%29-12% is a term

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to generate the query you need via the fluent interface, feel free to use **whereRaw** and **REGEXP**:

```
$kslr=DB::table('kisiler')
  ->select('*')
  ->whereRaw("dogumgunu REGEXP '^[0-9]-[0-9]'")
  ->get();
```

Example;

```
$kslr=DB::table('kisiler')
  ->select('*')
  ->whereRaw("dogumgunu REGEXP '^29-12'")
  ->get();
```

Comment: Yes, I live in Turkey.